# Sql update query with Single quotes

Tags: java, sql

I am using hibernate application in java to retrieve and update database.

During updating a table,i forming an sql query as follows,

```
String qry = "UPDATE " + entity  + " SET " + htmlColumn + " ='"+value+"' WHERE " + id + " = " + primaryId;
```

**where value is a html string which contains single quotes sometimes.**

How to escape ignore/escape the single quotes and update the table successfully

Thanks

Comment: You are saying that you are using hibernate. I don't think that you should be writing that kind of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set values directly.

```
currentSession()
    .createQuery("UPDATE " + entity  + " SET " + htmlColumn +
              " = :value WHERE " + id + " :id")
    .setParameter("value", value).setParameter(":id",id).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-named-parameters-examples-in-simplejdbctemplate/

Answer (score 3):

use `PreparedStatement` for this

```
String qry = "UPDATE " + entity  + 
             " SET " + htmlColumn + " = ? " +
             "WHERE " + id + " = ?";

PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
pstmt.setString(1, value);
pstmt.setInt(2, primaryId);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Yes this is the best way of doing this, I also suggested the same,
+1 for posting before me :-)

Comment: Or use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the single quote with a double single quote. `value.replace("'","''");` but you will need to cater for more than just that because your value can easily allow for SQL Injection if it is not properly catered for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preparedstatement as :

```
String query= "UPDATE " + entity  + " SET " + htmlColumn + " =? WHERE " + id + " = " + primaryId;

PreparedStatement ptmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
ptmt.setString(1, value);
```